# ASP.NET jQuery Menu blinks on postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, postback

I have a simple *aspx* page like this:

```html
<!-- Other code -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu();
    });
</script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Action1
        <ul>
            <li>Action1-1</li>
            <li>Action1-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<!-- Other code -->
```

When **LinkButton** is clicked (PostBack), page is blinking in **IE11**, **Chrome**, **Opera**.
At the same time in **Firefox** everything is OK.

Looks like it renders **UL** on page as list and then make it as menu and first step is visible in browser.

Help me to solve this problem, because page has a lot of PostBack actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, ASP.Net LinkButton does a postback. This then reloads the entire page from the server so your menu is reloaded and you will see the page redrawn.

You can put your non-static content inside an UpdatePanel so that only that section of the page is loaded.

```
<!-- Other code -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu();
    });
</script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Action1
        <ul>
            <li>Action1-1</li>
            <li>Action1-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <!-- Other code -->
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

To use an UpdatePanel, you will need to include a ScriptManager, probably in your master page. A quick search for UpdatePanel should get you the information you need to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set to all your ul items on second and other levels to display:none
and add following lines to your initialization string:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.menu').menu();
    $('.menu li ul').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting:

```
<ul class="menu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <li>Action1
        <ul style="display: none">
            <li>Action1-1</li>
            <li>Action1-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

blinking became not so annoying.

But it does not prevent blinking.
Problem can be solved by **UpdatePanel**, but this is not suitable for me for some reasons